# Server-side rendering for Angular stopped working after update from Angular 8 to Angular 11

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

As the title says, angular server side rendering stopped working after a major Angular update to version 11 on my project.

The concrete problems i'm getting is with dependency injection. I'm getting the errors like this:

`Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LibraryRouteComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

The errors go away when i manually do @Inject in the constructor of the components, services, guards which in my guess should now work like that, as i should put @Inject() in every constructor of every Angular component to make it work and there is already @Injectable() decorator at the relevant Angular components.

It's worth noting that the app builds and runs without any problems, only SSR stopped working. And i followed [this guide](https://www.ganatan.com/tutorials/server-side-rendering-with-angular-universal) about making transitions from SSR used on Angular 8 to higher versions.

I tried making an empty Angular 11 project with some component and services insertions and dependency injection and everything was working fine there. And i was looking for the versions to match and be exactly the same.

The issue i'm experiencing may be relevant to this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35924#issuecomment-634341638) but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help is really appreciated as it's taking quite some time to resolve the issue.